# Non-Standard Date Format in ASP.NET MVC, Telerik Kendo, jQuery validation

Tags: jquery, date, format, kendo-asp.net-mvc, culture

How does one add a new date format to ASP.NET MVC 4, Telerik Kendo (and its DatePicker), with jQuery validation also present?

Answer (score 0):

I've provided detailed information on one way to accomplish this:

http://bradfultonprogramming.blogspot.com/2014/04/a-non-standard-date-format-with-aspnet.html